# Continuous Full GC even though Old Generation is not filled up

Tags: java, garbage-collection, jvm-hotspot

Every few days we see continuous Full GC (more than 1000 FullGC's)  and then the application comes to normal...the verbose GC log is as below .. when it is doing Full GC, the old generation is not filled up.. but what is prompting this Full Gc??

## Environment/Settings

JDK 1.6
Memory Settings -Xms256M -Xmx2048M -XX:MaxPermSize=512M

Attaching to process ID 25118, please wait...
Debugger attached successfully.
Server compiler detected.
JVM version is 14.3-b01

using thread-local object allocation.
Parallel GC with 8 thread(s)

Heap Configuration:
   MinHeapFreeRatio = 40
   MaxHeapFreeRatio = 70
   MaxHeapSize      = 2147483648 (2048.0MB)
   NewSize          = 2686976 (2.5625MB)
   MaxNewSize       = 17592186044415 MB
   OldSize          = 5439488 (5.1875MB)
   NewRatio         = 2
   SurvivorRatio    = 8
   PermSize         = 21757952 (20.75MB)
   MaxPermSize      = 536870912 (512.0MB)

```
404006.016: [GC [PSYoungGen: 242756K->10659K(249408K)] 609285K->378416K(825536K), 0.0244300 secs] [Times: user=0.09 sys=0.00, real=0.03 secs]   
404126.211: [GC [PSYoungGen: 239715K->11421K(250624K)] 607472K->379300K(826752K), 0.0314540 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]   
404498.907: [GC [PSYoungGen: 241181K->15113K(250816K)] 609060K->383750K(826944K), 0.0567160 secs] [Times: user=0.11 sys=0.00, real=0.06 secs]   
404559.340: [GC [PSYoungGen: 81552K->9784K(250688K)] 450190K->378571K(826816K), 0.0255340 secs] [Times: user=0.08 sys=0.01, real=0.03 secs]   
404559.366: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 9784K->0K(250688K)] [PSOldGen: 368787K->225993K(576128K)] 378571K->225993K(826816K) [PSPermGen: 181648K->181648K(187968K)], 1.4180830 secs] [Times: user=1.42 sys=0.00, real=1.42 secs]   
404560.791: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1155K->64K(251072K)] 227148K->226057K(827200K), 0.0141730 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs]   
404560.806: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 64K->0K(251072K)] [PSOldGen: 225993K->202050K(576128K)] 226057K->202050K(827200K) [PSPermGen: 181648K->178996K(185216K)], 1.5066450 secs] [Times: user=1.50 sys=0.00, real=1.51 secs]   
404562.329: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1351K->272K(252032K)] 203401K->202322K(828160K), 0.0129750 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]   
404562.342: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 272K->0K(252032K)] [PSOldGen: 202050K->202125K(576128K)] 202322K->202125K(828160K) [PSPermGen: 178996K->178996K(184512K)], 1.3184310 secs] [Times: user=1.32 sys=0.00, real=1.32 secs]   
404563.674: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1146K->128K(253312K)] 203271K->202253K(829440K), 0.0106520 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]   
404563.685: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 128K->0K(253312K)] [PSOldGen: 202125K->202126K(576128K)] 202253K->202126K(829440K) [PSPermGen: 178997K->178997K(184000K)], 1.3197180 secs] [Times: user=1.32 sys=0.00, real=1.32 secs]   
404565.025: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1146K->64K(254976K)] 203272K->202190K(831104K), 0.0152030 secs] [Times: user=0.03 sys=0.01, real=0.01 secs]   
404565.041: [Full GC (System) [PSYoungGen: 64K->0K(254976K)] [PSOldGen: 202126K->202126K(576128K)] 202190K->202126K(831104K) [PSPermGen: 178997K->178997K(183296K)], 1.3072740 secs] [Times: user=1.31 sys=0.00, real=1.31 secs]   
404566.355: [GC [PSYoungGen: 1151K->160K(255360K)] 203278K->202286K(831488K), 0.0107640 secs] [Times: user=0.02 sys=0.02, real=0.01 secs]
```

Comment: Please give us details about your environment including your language and garbage collector.  There are a lot of things that can cause misbehavior like this, but they will be specific to your situation.

Answer (score 3):

The PermGen is filling up: [PSPermGen: 178997K->178997K(183296K)]

That's the space that contains information about classes that are loaded into the JVM, you may want to add -XX:+TraceClassLoading -XX:+TraceClassUnloading to see why it's getting so big although you can also increase the size of the PermGen by specifying -XX:MaxPermSize=512M. A setting of 512M is not uncommon.